# How do I make MySql use the most efficient index when joining?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables - `products` and `items`. There is a 1:M relationship there, where `items.product_id` points to `products.id`.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT products.* FROM products 
ORDER BY created_at desc 
LIMIT 1
```

which performs fine. However, now I join items on to it:

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
JOIN items ON items.product_id = products.id 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY created_at desc 
LIMIT 1
```

and the query runs unacceptably slow (~5 secs. with the current amount of data)

Explain outputs:

```
mysql> explain SELECT products.* FROM products GROUP BY id  ORDER BY created_at desc  LIMIT 1 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: products
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_products_on_first_created_at
          key: index_products_on_first_created_at
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
```

and:

```
mysql> explain SELECT products.*  FROM products  JOIN items ON items.product_id = products.id  GROUP BY id  ORDER BY created_at desc  LIMIT 1 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: products
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_products_on_first_created_at
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 261734
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: items
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_items_on_product_id
          key: index_items_on_product_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: foobar_development.products.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

So basically, when I join (and group), MySql is no longer using the index for `created_at`, thrashing its ability to properly sort the result. I tried to create a combined index with `id` + `created_at`, but the query plan ignores it. E.g.:

```
alter table products add index foobar (id,created_at) ;
```

What can I do to make this query perform better?

Comment: It's not using the index because you aren't sorting on the column from products in the second query, it's sorting the result set. Sorting is done after selecting.

Comment: Despite joining it, you're not using the `items` table.  What is the purpose of the join?  Perhaps there is a better solution to what you need?

Comment: Andrew: I believe you're right about that, but what can I do about it?

Comment: Eggyal: Well, I simplified the query for this post. In reality I have some conditions in a where clause, but that didn't seem central to the problem.

Comment: @troelskn: Without a ton of information, it's hard to say. But one easy thing to try is indexing the columns you're joining on. Do you have any constraints in your real query?